# Querying all images in folder using GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am currently learning Gatsby.js and GraphQL as a supplementary technology and got stuck with querying. I want to query all images from a folder, map trough them and display them in a react component as a grid. I am using gatsby-source-filesystem but can't figure out, how to address specifically that folder and get all images from it.

My plugin set up for source-filesystem looks like this.

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/src/posts`,
    name: 'posts',
  },
},
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `images`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/assets/images`,
  },
},
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `photos`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/assets/photos`,
  },
},
```

I have my images in src/assets/photos

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can select specific folders using filters in graphql.

Try something like this:

```
query AssetsPhotos {
  allFile(filter: {extension: {regex: "/(jpg)|(jpeg)|(png)/"}, relativeDirectory: {eq: "photos"}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where `eq: photos` should be changed to the relative directory result you get for the files you want to target when you go to GraphiQL and run a query on `allFile`.

Comment: You save my day men! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 13):

I like to use `sourceInstanceName` when using `gatsby-source-filesystem` plugin as documented in the [plugin docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-filesystem/#how-to-query).

Your `gatsby-config.js`

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/content/legal`,
    name: "legal", // IMPORTANT: the name of your source instance
  },
}, {
  resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/content/blog`,
    name: "blog",
  },
}
```

Then you can directly address them in your GraphQL query using `filter` and `sourceInstanceName`:

```
export const query = graphql`
{
  allFile(filter: {
      extension: {eq: "png"},
      sourceInstanceName: {eq: "blog"}
    })
  {
    edges {
      node {
      childImageSharp {
          fluid(maxWidth: 300, quality: 50) {
            originalName
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In contrast to `relativeDirectory`, this way you never have to deal with changing relative paths you might refactor your project or whatever. Just let GraphQL handle it for you!

Comment: This is an elegant solution