# What is the best way to display all pictures of a directory in a Gatsby project using React?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby, image-loading

I am using GatsbyJS starter https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/codebushi/gatsby-starter-forty/ and have a need to display all pictures from a directory on a page. Gatsby's recommended way to import media is to use `import` statement, but it results in hashes added to the file names after the build. For example: 
`/static/pic09-d59e4b49832baeb9c62a7a9d6c070f8c.jpg`

If I retrieve all filenames from a directory and try to create `<img>` elements with `src={fileName}` it results in empty images, because file names does not match with the ones from the server already with hashes appended.

Please recommend an elegant solution on how to go through this. My backup plan is to put everything to the `static` directory where hashes are not being added, but it is not recommended way by Gatsby documentation: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-folder/

This is what I have now:

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/layout'

class Gallery extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const images = [];
        const req = require.context('../assets/images/signboards', false);
        req.keys().forEach(function (key) {
            images.push(key.substr(1));
        });
        return (
            <Layout>
                <div id="main">
                    <section className="spotlights">
                        <section>
                            {images.map((image) => {
                                return (
                                <div className="image">
                                <img src={'../assets/images/signboards' + image} alt="" />
                            </div>
                                )
                            })}
                        </section>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </Layout>
        )
    }
}

export default Gallery;
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querying all images in folder using GraphQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349801/querying-all-images-in-folder-using-graphql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: this answer assumes you have already installed `gatsby-source-filesystem`, `gatsby-transformer-sharp` and `gatsby-plugin-sharp`.

---

You can use a graphql page query to get all of the files of a certain extension, in a certain folder by filtering `allFile` with a combination of regular expression matchers.

Then you can loop through the resulting edges and use `gatsby-image` to display the image.

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from 'gatsby-image'

const IndexPage = ({data}) => (
  <>
    {data.allFile.edges.map(edge => {
      return <Img fluid={edge.node.childImageSharp.fluid} />
    })}
  </>
)

export default IndexPage

export const indexQuery = graphql`
  query AssetsPhotos {
    allFile(filter: {extension: {regex: "/(jpg)|(jpeg)|(png)/"}, dir: {regex: "/assets/images/signboards"}}) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 300) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: Thank you, this kind of put me on the way. But how do I pass query result to the component? I'm getting the `data` variable as `undefined`.

Comment: The `data` prop contains the results of the GraphQL page query. You can pass all or some of it to any components.

Comment: Hi man, it'e been a while since you answered it. I implemented it like thisa and now after my project is done i find my bundle size beeing very large, due the rendering of all images in all fluid expressions. Can we somehow improve this to not bloat our final bundle? Just asking.

Comment: I guess it depends on the filter you used in your query. Best to create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gatsby-source-filesystem plugin. 
install the plugin:

npm install --save gatsby-source-filesystem

Register a folder or other filters(extenssion, etc.) in the gatsby.config.js and give it a name.

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/src/pages/type1`,
    name: 'data',
  },
},
```

Then build query like this, in the component:

```
{
allFile(filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "data" } }) {
edges {
  node {
    extension
    dir
    modifiedTime
  }
} }}
```

You can have many of these "registrations" providing different data(folder, extension, etc.)