# Query folder usign Graphql and gatsby-source-filesystem

Tags: graphql, filesystems, gatsby

## Edit

I think i was not clear about my problem.

The problem is that `sourceInstanceName` is returning the empty array shown in the question even though the folder has content and .md files.

Hello everyone I've been having problem querying the folders with graphql.

You see I have this file structure:

```bash
/content/posts/Journeys/{FILENAME}.{EXTENSION}
/content/posts/Blog/{FILENAME}.{EXTENSION}
```

I would like to query the **FOLDER NAME** (aka Journeys or BLOG) not the content.

I'm able to query using this:

```
query test2 {
  journeys: allFile(filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "posts"}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        dir
        name
        relativePath
        relativeDirectory
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns this, where it return unnecessary files as I just want the folder name or directory:

```
{
  "data": {
    "journeys": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "dir": "D:/Side-projects/salomonpina.dev/content",
            "name": ".git",
            "relativePath": ".git",
            "relativeDirectory": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "dir": "D:/Side-projects/salomonpina.dev/content/icons/png",
            "name": "github-icon_512",
            "relativePath": "icons/png/github-icon_512.png",
            "relativeDirectory": "icons/png"
          }
        },

more info down...
```

And it also work for **Assets**

But when I change `(filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "posts"}})` to `(filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "journeys"}})`

It returns an empty array:

```
{
  "data": {
    "journeys": {
      "edges": []
    }
  }
}
```

Even though its using the correct name, the one coming from `gatsby-source-filesystem`.

Here's what I did in `gatsby-config.js` and the `gatsby-source-filesystem`.

```js
{
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "posts",
        path: `${__dirname}/content/`,
      },
    },

    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "assets",
        path: `${__dirname}/static/`,
      },
    },

    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "journeys",
        path: `${__dirname}/content/posts/Journeys/`,
      },
    },
```

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349801/querying-all-images-in-folder-using-graphql) but doesn't seem to help me out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the folder for each `post`?

Comment: Yes, the folder name for each post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lack of information about the type of data (extension) of the files that will affect how you should gather your `post` information. What you need to do once you get the `sourceInstanceName` access directly to the content itself. Assuming you have a markdown structure, this will be `childMarkdownRemark`, so this should work:

```
{
  allFile(filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "journeys"}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        sourceInstanceName
        childMarkdownRemark {
          frontmatter {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Note: your nested structure since `childMarkdownRemark` object may differ from mine. Check the `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground to see which is your query object.*

In addition, I think you are missing a filesystem in your `gatsby-node.js` for your Blog folder:

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
  options: {
    name: "blog",
    path: `${__dirname}/content/posts/Blog/`,
  },
},
```

If you don't retrieve any value from your query, remove the `filter` to check what's the `sourceInstanceName` of each `post` (to check if they are properly set or the filter doesn't work due to a typo). Check them in `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground.

---

I don't know your requirements or specifications but, maybe adding another field in your `post` GraphQL schema fits for you too, let's say `category` (`journey` or `blog`) is valid and more scalable for you, as an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! The blog folder and filesystem for it has been added but I think i was not clear about my problem. The problem is that `sourceInstanceName` is returning the empty array shown in the question even though the folder has content and .md files

Comment: In that case, I would suggest removing the filter and try to query all your `sourceInstanceName` and see if they are well retrieved. Then I would try to add the filtering.